# JavaScript, Web API import with D3 (Data Driven Document)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, webapi

I'd like to import data from an Web API (JSON format) and use it for visualization. As you see in the following code, I've already implemented everything and it works (almost).

Question: The `dataExport` isn't the same as `data`. Why? How can I change my code so that `dataExport` the same like `data`?

**Code:**

```
var dataExport = d3.json("http://link to the Server...", function(error, data){
            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(data);

                console.log(data.collection.items);
            }
});
        
console.log(dataExport);
```

**Console.log(data);**

```
Object {collection: Object}
collection: Object
href: "http://link to the Server..."
items: Array[50]
links: Array[1]
queries: Array[1]
version: "1.0"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

**Console.log(dataExport);**

```
Object {header: function, mimeType: function, responseType: function, response: function, get: function…}
abort: function (){return c.abort(),i}
get: function (){return i.send.apply(i,[n].concat(Qo(arguments)))}
header: function (n,t){return n=(n+"").toLowerCase(),arguments.length<2?a[n]:(null==t?delete a[n]:a[n]=t+"",i)}
mimeType: function (n){return arguments.length?(t=null==n?null:n+"",i):t}
on: function (){var r=e.apply(t,arguments);return r===t?n:r}
post: function (){return i.send.apply(i,[n].concat(Qo(arguments)))}
response: function (n){return e=n,i}
responseType: function (n){return arguments.length?(s=n,i):s}
send: function (e,r,u){if(2===arguments.length&&"function"==typeof r&&(u=r,r=null),c.open(e,n,!0),null==t||"accept"in a||(a.accept=t+",*/*"),c.setRequestHeader)for(var l in a)c.setRequestHeader(l,a[l]);return null!=t&&c.overrideMimeType&&c.overrideMimeType(t),null!=s&&(c.responseType=s),null!=u&&i.on("error",u).on("load",function(n){u(null,n)}),o.beforesend.call(i,c),c.send(null==r?null:r),i}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you store the whole parsing-process in your dataStore-variable, while the data-variable only contains the data you call within the d3.json - as it should be.

you don't need to use another variable, so just try

```
d3.json("http://link to the Server...", function(error, dataStore){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(dataStore);

            console.log(dataStore.collection.items);
        }
});
```

dataStore should contain the wanted results

edit: to access it outside the d3.json

```
var dataStore; //declare a global variable somewhere at the beginning of your script
```

and then

```
d3.json("http://link to the Server...", function(error, data){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        dataStore=data;
    }
});

console.log(dataStore);
console.log(dataStore.collection.items);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But in this case, `dataStore` is not defined outside of the d3.json(...); I think, it has to be for the export.

Comment: then you could just declare it as a global variable in the beginning of your script, and put `dataStore=data;` in place - see the edit in the answer